# Random skill not functioning as expected in Python text rpg

Tags: python, random, text-based

I'm having some trouble handling basic skill increases. Right now the code looks like

```
huntluck = 11
huntskill = 1

def hunt(self):
    global result, huntluck, huntskill

    hunting = random.randint(0, huntluck)

    if hunting == 0:
        result = "You couldn't find anything."
    elif hunting >=10:
        huntluck += 1
        huntskill += 1
        result = ("You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. " +
        "(%s)" %huntskill)
```

Luck and skill are separate because I wanted the chance for hunt lvl 1 to succeed to be one in ten, but I also wanted to display the skill properly. It's a pretty hamhanded approach, but that's only part of the trouble.

Everything prints right, but when the user succeeds, there's like about a 50/50 chance the skill level won't go up.

> You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. (2)
>
> You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. (2)
>
> You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. (3)
>
> You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. (3)
>
> You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. (3)
>
> You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. (4)

I intend for the skill level to raise every time the player succeeds at hunting. Obviously that's not happening...

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it? How can I do things better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only set a new value for `result` if `hunting` is equal to 0 *or* larger than 9. If `hunting` is equal to 1-9, then `result` remains the old value, and you reprint that.

Change your `hunting` test:

```
if hunting < 10:
    result = "You couldn't find anything."
else:
    huntluck += 1
    huntskill += 1
    result = ("You succeeded in hunting. Your hunting skill increases. " +
    "(%s)" %huntskill)
```

Comment: Oh frick! That would explain it! That's what I get for coding in the middle of the night. Thank you!